# PHP Dynamic Colorbox with Multiple Galleries

Tags: php, jquery, gallery, colorbox

I have dynamic gallery generated from a php code, wich are represented by one picture only. When you select that picture, it should open a color box with multiples photos.

The problem is, my colorbox seem to not recognize my rel.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements

            $("a.gallery").click(function(){
                var galleryRelative = $(this).attr("rel");
                alert(galleryRelative);

                $(this).colorbox({rel:galleryRelative});

            });
        });
    </script>
```

And my HTML

```
foreach($kittens as $key => $kitten){                 

    echo '<div class="block1 smallblock">';

    echo '<a class="gallery" rel="gallery0" title="blablabla" href="../img/block-03.jpg"> 
             <img src="../img/block-03.jpg" width="299" height="233" alt="kitten" />
          </a>';

    echo '<p><a href="../img/block-03.jpg" rel="gallery0" title="blabla"></a></p>';
    echo '<p><a href="../img/block-02.jpg" rel="gallery0" title="blabla"></a></p>';

    echo '</div>';
}
```

I will generate the gallery0 without problems (im reading with success the rel attribute from my a.gallery in my script, but colorbox won't match it.

Answer (score 1):

Colorbox will use your rel attribute by default.  Just use:

```
$("a.gallery").colorbox();
```

By setting your own click event you are reassigning colorbox to your elements each time an item is clicked, which would be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can better try with the Pretty Photo plugin for displaying the multiple photos in the light box by clicking the single image. I used the Pikachoose gallery when i click the image from PikaChoose I show the list of images inside the light box using the Pretty Photo Plugin [demo for Pretty](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/). Hope this may be useful for you